# Angular 6 attribute directive field undefined

Tags: angular

I work with Angular 6. I have a form with  4 fields. Two of them are the price and the quantity. I want to display in another field the multiplication  of price and quantity.

I defined an attribute directive. I want to display in a div the field of directive paModel totalPrice. I defined an event in the form fields.

This is my form

```html
<form novalidate [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm(form)">
  <div class="form-group" *ngFor="let control of form.productControls">
    <label>{{ control.label }}</label>
    <input
      class="form-control"
      [(ngModel)]="newProduct[control.modelProperty]"
      name="{{ control.modelProperty }}"
      formControlName="{{ control.modelProperty }}"
      [paModel]="newProduct[control.modelProperty]"
      (paModelChange)="newProduct[control.modelProperty] = $event"
      [pa-product]="newProduct"
      #paModel="paModel"
    />
    <ul class="text-danger list-unstyled" *ngIf="(formSubmitted || control.dirty) && !control.valid">
      <li *ngFor="let error of control.getValidationMessages()">{{ error }}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="bg-primary text-white">{{ paModel.totalPrice }}</div>
  <button
    class="btn btn-primary"
    type="submit"
    [disabled]="formSubmitted && !form.valid"
    [class.btn-secondary]="formSubmitted && !form.valid"
  >
    Create
  </button>
</form>
```

The attribute directive name is paModel. This is my paModel directive

```js
import { Input, Output, EventEmitter, Directive, HostBinding, HostListener, SimpleChange } from "@angular/core";
import {Product } from "./product.model"

@Directive({
    selector: "input[paModel]",
    exportAs: "paModel"
})
export class PaModel {

    direction: string = "None";

    @Output("pa-totalprice")
    totalPrice: number = 0;

    @Input("paModel")
    modelProperty: string;

    @Input("pa-product")
    product: Product;

    @HostBinding("value")
    fieldValue: string = "";

    ngOnChanges(changes: { [property: string]: SimpleChange }) {
        console.log("en ngOnChanges");
        let change = changes["modelProperty"];
        if (change.currentValue != this.fieldValue) {
            this.fieldValue = changes["modelProperty"].currentValue || "";
            this.direction = "Model";
            this.totalPrice = 0;
        }
    }

    @Output("paModelChange")
    update = new EventEmitter<string>();

    @HostListener("input", ["$event.target.value"])
    updateValue(newValue: string) {
        console.log("en updateValue");
        console.log("name ",this.product.name)
        console.log("price ",this.product.price)
        console.log("quantity ",this.product.quantity)
        if (this.product.price != undefined && this.product.quantity != undefined) {
            this.totalPrice = this.product.price * this.product.quantity;
        } else {
            this.totalPrice = 0;
        }
        this.fieldValue = newValue;
        this.update.emit(newValue);
        this.direction = "Element";
    }
}
```

In the console I see the error

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalPrice' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateRenderer] (ProductFormComponent.html:18)
    at Object.debugUpdateRenderer [as updateRenderer] (core.js:10879)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10255)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10491)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10433)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10256)
    at callViewAction (core.js:10491)
    at execComponentViewsAction (core.js:10433)
    at checkAndUpdateView (core.js:10256)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:11143)
```

How can I display the field totalPrice in a div?

**EDITED**

I modified my code. Now I have the html

```html
<div class="form-group bg-info text-white p-2">
  <input class="bg-primary text-white" [(paModel)]="newProduct" #paModel="paModel" />
  <div *ngIf="paModel" class="bg-primary text-white">Total Price : {{ paModel.totalPriceString }}</div>
</div>
```

And I have two methods

```js
ngOnChanges(changes: { [property: string]: SimpleChange }) {

    let change = changes["modelProperty"];
    /* if (change.currentValue != this.fieldValue) { */

        this.fieldValue = changes["modelProperty"].currentValue || "";

        this.direction = "Model";
        if (this.product.price != undefined && this.product.quantity != undefined) {
        this.totalPrice = this.product.price * this.product.quantity;
    } else {

        this.totalPrice = 0;
    }

    this.totalPriceString = this.totalPrice.toString();

   /*  } */
}

@Output("paModelChange")
update = new EventEmitter<string>();

@HostListener("input", ["$event.target.value"])
updateValue(newValue: string) {

    if (this.product.price != undefined && this.product.quantity != undefined) {
        this.totalPrice = this.product.price * this.product.quantity;
    } else {
        this.totalPrice = 0;
    }
    this.fieldValue = newValue;


    this.update.emit(newValue);
    this.direction = "Element";
    this.totalPriceString = this.totalPrice.toString();
}
```

At the end of these methods totalPrice has the multiplication, but the values is no displayed in the div.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Shouldnt it be `paModel.pa-totalprice` ?

Comment: I wrote <div class="bg-primary text-white">Total Price:{{paModel.pa-totalprice}}</div> but I get the error Multiple markers at this line
- Identifier 'pa' is not defined. 'PaModel' does not contain such a member
- Identifier 'totalprice' is not defined. The component declaration, template variable declarations, and element references do not contain such a member

Comment: Yeah I think it's because of the dash in the variable name.  In your Output statement, change the name to camel case `Output('paTotalPrice') totalPrice: number = 0;` . And then update in the html too.  Does that help?

Comment: I wrote <div class="bg-primary text-white">Total Price{{paModel.paTotalPrice}}</div> but I get  Identifier 'paTotalPrice' is not defined. 'PaModel' does not contain such a member

Comment: What do you mean the values is no display? Are these values the quantity and the price or you mean the totalprice?

Comment: totalprice is not displayed

Comment: You say you try to show the totalprice but you just try to show the totalPriceString even if this variable is not define in to your directive? Can be any typo on your code example?

Comment: I tried and defined both totalprice and totalPriceString, but neither of them are displayed. My problem is that  paModel is undefined. I fixed this error defining paModel in a input, but I only want to display  {{paModel.totalPrice}} in a div. Also, if I move the div inside the for displaying the form field, paModel is defined, but it displays a div for each input field

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your input, you should be trying to access `modelProperty`, not `paModel`

```
@Input("paModel") modelProperty: string; // in the current component it is modelProperty
```

And then I am guessing you are trying to access the child before the data is passed in, thus it is `undefined` until the value gets passed in. So your html should look like this

```
<div class="bg-primary text-white">{{modelProperty?.totalPrice}}</div>
```

or like this

```
<div *ngIf="paModel" class="bg-primary text-white">{{paModel.totalPrice}}</div>
```

The `?` operator will only show the child value if the parent object is defined. Or you could use an `*ngIf` to remove the html from the dom until the value is defined.

Comment: My Good! What do you want to do? Decided if you want to use Template driven Form or Reactive Forms, to show the total of a line simply {{quantity*cant}}, to show the total price use a getter that sum the quantity*cant.- first map the values, then reduce

Comment: @Carlota There is too much going on in your code. you have a `formControlName` and an `ngModel` on the same element which you can't have. Your inputs are being renamed but then you try accessing them by the original name in the html. Honestly I don't think I can help unless you add a stackblitz or something.